# Excel: OLE DB Oracle connection - Save Password for refresh

Tags: excel, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

So, I'm using an Excel file that contains several connections to an Oracle database targetting different SQL views. All the views are on the same server for the same user. The problem is, everytime I refresh the datas on the excel ("refresh all"), I have to enter the password for every connection, in my case, one connection = one view. Is there any way to either type in the password only one time when the data needs to be refreshed or either make the excel file retains the user's password.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found it. In excel, in the data tab -> Connections -> properties (of a connection) -> Definition tab, there is a check box to save the password. However it's saved without encryption, so be careful.